# How to make shell output redirect (>) write while script is still running?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, command-line

I wrote a short script that never terminates. This script continuously generates output that I have to check on every now and then. I'm running it on a lab computer through SSH, and redirecting the output to a file in my public_html folder on that machine.

```
python script.py > ~/public_html/results.txt
```

However, the results don't show up immediately when I refresh the address. The results show up when I terminate the program, but as I said, it doesn't halt by itself. Is that redirect (`>`) being lazy with with writing? Is there a way to continuously (or with an interval) update the results in the file?

Or is it the webserver that doesn't update the file while it is still being written?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to flush the output `sys.stdout.flush()` (or smth) if you want to see it immediately. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll try it right away.

I didn't think it was _python_ buffering output.

--edit: I tried, it makes no difference. so either `>` is buffering, or the webserver.

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment, I was being impatient. It' still not "real-time" but that's probably browser cache.

Answer (score 7):

*stdout* is buffered, if not connected to terminal.

You can change this policy to line-buffering via **stdbuf**

```
stdbuf -oL python script.py > ~/public_html/results.txt
```

So you don't have to flush in  your Python script and keep it IO efficient, if line-buffering is not required.

Comment: Will this be less efficient than python's `flush()` if called sparingly? I use `flush()` now and it's called less than once per line.

Comment: I doubt there will be a difference, because data will most likely not be written to disk if you don't use flush(3).

If you use your app on a terminal line-buffering will be default. For long running background jobs, redirecting to a file will choose more efficient buffering.

For special cases like yours, you can always use stdbuf and thus keep IO-Code out of your app, keeping it flexible and more readable.

Comment: Where can I find stdbuf on ubuntu? doesn't seem to be included in the coreutils package

Comment: I actually prefer this over the accepted answer, as it's more general and does not require source modification. (Or in more technical terms, it's absolutely ballin'.)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the file is being continuously written, but that the web server is reporting the modified date of the file as the time it was opened, and thus is reporting that no change to the file has occurred and the result is being cached (either at the web server or at the client).

I would first try a forced reload (Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R or Shift+<reload_button>) and see if that helps. If it doesn't, then you can try something else.

In a separate shell on the server, do

```
tail -f ~/public_html/results.txt
```

Tail prints out the last n lines of the file (where n defaults to 10), but the -f parameter monitors the file and continues to report output as the file grows. This will at least give you confidence that the file is being written to incrementally.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, nc3b's solution worked. Tail shows the newest results as they are written. The browser view updates in batches every short period of time now. Forced refresh doesn't change that. But it's quick enough.