# output redirect - how to get reatime streaming using tail -f

Tags: logging, ubuntu

I am using runnit to run a python process on ubuntu.  I redirect the output of the program to a log file.

```
exec /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/workspace/monitor.py >> /tmp/monitor.out 2>&1
```

I then use

```
tail -f /tmp/monitor.out
```

to have a look at what is going on.

Howerver, it output is not streaming.  Always behind, some times by a few minutes.  Its not a lot of output.

How do I get realtime streaming?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with redirected output being buffered. Maybe one of these links would be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753350 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055918

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll post that as an answer since it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is probably being buffered. Put `sys.stdout.flush()` somewhere at the end of the script's loop to write the buffer to disk immediately. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2753361/392143) for more information)